# Specific transit service not appearing in transit layer Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to display the [MART](http://www.mrta.us/) transit system on a web map I'm building with the Javascript API. It's listed [here](https://www.google.com/landing/transit/cities/index.html#NorthAmerica) by Google as one of the cities that they have transit data for, and indeed when you go to Google Maps there is bus data there.

The transit layer example page listed here works and displays transit data for Boston, Chicago, DC, etc, but not MART. Code as follows:

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 42.54, lng: -71.79}
    });

    var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
    transitLayer.setMap(map);
    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyChFsvLbqcDVBUQMFQJaMxA19PhTys6ZxY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
```

Seems like it should work but no luck. The map appears, centered in the correct location, but no transit data for MART. If you go look at Boston, however, the transit layer appears there (as well as DC, Chicago, etc). In general it seems to be displaying train lines only but no bus lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a div(or an element) with an id of map asin `<div id="map"></div>`

Comment: @richard4s Yes, I'll edit above to show the full script.

Answer (score -1):

**You might to add some css because it's working but not showing**

```
<style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
```

Here's a link to my working version

> https://jsfiddle.net/mpuzz0tb/6/

If you want to show a map for both transit and bicycles, You need two seperate `ids` for the maps to be displayed - @dalewatt